# SBT: How to set common scala version for multiproject

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-SBT-project in IntellJ Idea. My SBT file in the root dir looks like this:

```
name := "PlayRoot"

version := "1.0"

lazy val shapeless_learn = project.in(file("shapeless_learn")).dependsOn(common)
lazy val scalaz_learn = project.in(file("scalaz_learn")).dependsOn(common)
lazy val common = project.in(file("common"))

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(common, shapeless_learn, scalaz_learn)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Then I have folders for each of the projects: `./common`, `./shapeless_learn`, `./scalaz_learn` and each has its own `build.sbt` there. But for some reason I require to put in each of the subproject `build.sbt` files the line `scalaVersion := "2.11.7"`.

If I forget to do that, the build fails with the message:

```
Error:Unresolved dependencies: common#common_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
See complete log in ...
```

For some reason if I do not specify that my scala version is `2.11.7`, sbt falls back to `2.10` and tries to find `common` project that is built for `2.10` which I do not have.

I always keep forgetting adding `scalaVersion := "2.11.7"` to the newly created project and it keeps bugging me. I also would prefer sbt generating `build.sbt` with some default data, but instead it requires me not to forget to create it manually.

1. <strike>Is there any way I could set the single scala version for all projects and sub-projects in a single place?</strike> I figured that I could add a separate `lazy val commonSettings = Seq { scalaVersion := "2.11.7" }` in a root definition. And for each `lazy val project` definition I should add in the end `.settings(commonSettings)`. This is nice, but still doesn't look beautiful enough - I should do this for every project definition. Is there a better way?
2. Is there any way I could create a template for a newly created project, so when I just put line `lazy val newProject = ...`, it will put an appropriate `build.sbt` file there with the contents I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.7"
```

in the root `build.sbt`.